# Pagination with Sequelize raw query

Tags: node.js, graphql, pagination, sequelize.js, raw

I am trying to paginate my queries but there are raw queries. So I don't know how to do it.
So far I have seen two solutions: use LIMIT but from what I have read it is not a reliable method.
The second is to use FETCH but that is not a good solution either.

Im using node + graphql + sequelize.

This is my query:

```
const myQuery = db.sequelize.query(

            `

            SELECT alert.CodeDescription as AlertTypeDesc,

                employee.EmployeeId,

                concat(employee.LastName, ' ', employee.FirstName) as EmployeeData,

                IFNULL(alert.StartDate,'') as UTCStartMomentTS,

                IFNULL(alert.EndDate,'') as UTCStopMomentTS,                

                CASE WHEN year(alert.EndDate) IS NOT NULL

                    THEN SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, alert.StartDate, alert.EndDate))

                    ELSE SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, alert.StartDate, current_timestamp()))

                    END AS Duration,

                CASE WHEN alert.EndDate IS NULL

                    THEN 'Open'

                    ELSE 'Closed'

                    END AS Status

            FROM \`App.ScheduleAlert\` alert

                INNER JOIN \`Engine.Employee\` employee

                    ON alert.EmployeeKey = employee.EmployeeExternalKey

                INNER JOIN \`Engine.EmployeeAssignment\` employee_asg

                    ON employee.EmployeeId = employee_asg.EmployeeId

            WHERE employee_asg.SupervisorEmployeeId = $1

            AND alert.NominalDate = CURRENT_DATE()

            `,

            {

                bind: [employeeId],

                type: QueryTypes.SELECT

            },

        );
```

Has anyone ever done pagination like this, or know of any examples to look at?
I can't find anything like it. I believe the best way to do it is to transform this query, and all other queries like it, into a sequelize query and use limit and offset which are more reliable than SQL limit. But before taking this way I want to know if there is any solution for this problem.

Comment: `limit` and `offset` Sequelize options in a usual Sequelize queries through models are just translated as `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` options in a generated SQL query so can do the same in your raw query. These options are intended to be used in such tasks like pagination.

Comment: I'm searching for an option to Limit because this one doesn't work as I expected. And I can't figure out how to do without Limit.

Comment: Whta do you mean by `doesn't work`? No results? Errors? Unexpected results?